# What's a good solution for cleaning & including old data with new ones?

Tags: database, powerbi

Back in 2021, **Incidents**  & **Accidents** were under one report number: `I.R#`.

Now, due to the forms having more details, it's been decided to split these two, incidents as `I.R#` and accidents as `MVA#` each having its own database tables.

How to possibly move all `I.R#` numbers labeled as **Accidents** into `MVA#`? noting that these numbers are unique and must not be duplicated.

True that accidents either I.R or MVA are already labeled, but for the sake of statistics I do not want to show accidents in POWER BI twice.

Note:
The unique numbers are being saved in the DB as integers without the labels, aka `MVA#`.

Comment: You can use a calculated table like this... (note the constant value to show where the data is coming from in the resulting table)
:
SKinnyFACT = UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    'FactInternetSales',
       "CustomerKey", [CustomerKey],
        "DueDateKey",[DueDateKey],
        "Group","Group One"
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    'FactInternetSales',
    "CustomerKey", [CustomerKey],
        "DueDateKey",[DueDateKey],
        "Group","Group Two"
    )
)